# select multi row inside of a table (not same condition)

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I try to explain an issue I have faced nowadays. 
Actually I have designed a table in order to track the changes applying by users inside of a depot of NLP engine.

I have two table named Token And Lexeme. each token has an id that directly connect to a row of lexeme table. and always I can find the latest and updated lexemes by looking up to token table.

here is their scheme:

```
Token Table:
+-----+----------+----------+
| Id  | token    |LexemeId* |
+-----+----------+----------+
LexemeId refers to a row inside of lexeme table.
```

Lexeme Table:

```
+-----+---------------------+-------------+
| Id  | some information    |UpdatedFrom* |  
+-----+---------------------+-------------+
* UpdatedFrom field refers another row inside of Lexeme Table.
```

Null means there is no more rows related to this token(lexeme).

an example:

```
Token Table:
+-----+----------+----------+
| 0   | A        |4         |
| 1   | B        |1         |
+-----+----------+----------+


Lexeme Table:

+-----+----------------------+-------------+
| 0   | A information#1      |NULL         |  
| 1   | B information        |NULL         |  
| 2   | A information#2      |0            |  
| 3   | A information#3      |2            |
| 4   | A information#4      |3            |    
+-----+----------------------+-------------+
```

I hope I could clear the air.
I want to write a store procedure to collect all records related to each token. for example for token 'A', I'm expected to have an array (or data table) looks like this:

```
+-----+----------------------+-------------+
| id  | informations         | updated from|
+-----+----------------------+-------------+
| 0   | A information#1      |NULL         |  
| 2   | A information#2      |0            |  
| 3   | A information#3      |2            |
| 4   | A information#4      |3            |    
+-----+----------------------+-------------+
```

anybody has any idea to help me....

my knowledge on sql transcript is summarized to Update, Insert and select statements, not more!

thanks in advanced...

Comment: Which RDBMS (MySQL, Oracle, SQLServer, PostgreSQL, etc) is this? You can do this in a single query with most RDBMSs (via a recursive Common Table Expression), but MySQL would be the exception.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is in an RDBMS that supports recursive CTEs, try:

```
with cte as 
(select t.id TokenId, t.token, l.Id, l.SomeInformation, l.UpdatedFrom
 from Token t
 join Lexeme l on t.LexemeId = l.id
 union all
 select t.TokenId, t.token, l.Id, l.SomeInformation, l.UpdatedFrom
 from cte t
 join Lexeme l on t.UpdatedFrom = l.id)
select Id, SomeInformation, UpdatedFrom
from cte
where TokenId=0 /* token = 'A' */
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8571c/4).

Comment: Wow. I did not know that recursive `with` is possible. I tried it out under `oracle` which is my world and it still worked but it asks for a column list. The first line would then read `with cte (token,id, someinformation,updatedfrom) as`. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d226e/3

Comment: @hol: Yes, there are minor differences in recursive CTE syntax between RDBMSs that support them - in PostgreSQL, for example, you need to include the `recursive` keyword. As I recall, Oracle didn't support recursive CTEs before v11 (Oracle 10 had non-recursive CTEs), but you could always do somehting similar with `connect by`.

Comment: Yes, I am familiar with the `connect by` but this seems to me much easier (at least in certain circumstances).

Comment: @hol: Me, too! It's useful to be able to use `connect by` in older versions of Oracle, though.

Comment: Thanks Mark, Your code is very amazing and I didn't know about this ability on SQL transcripts. BUT, as i told before, I'm working on a NLP engine and I want to use sql server to store lexemes. you assumed on this code, that each token is unique, but in real world we can find many words with different meaning and pronunciation. for example "Patient  (noun) " and "patient (adjective)" so token "A" is not unique. I think I should handle it by coding outside SQL...

Comment: @Mostafa: If `token` on the Token table isn't unique, how about `id` on the Token table? (I have amended my query accordingly.) Alternatively, do you have another field you want to use for unique selection, such as the Token's `LexemeId`? If you can identify what processing you want done, it will generally be easier and more efficient to do it inside SQL. Also, which RDBMS are you using?